# How to hide the other contents in scroll spy instead of scroll to particular position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have some contents with some link.I am using here scrollspy. Whenever I click a link,its scrolling to particular div and menu will be active.But here instead of scrolling,I need to hide other div and show particular/matching div.I mean here instead of scroll I need to hide and show the contents. Here is the updated code https://plnkr.co/edit/VvV7T0FCdXirQfMROwi2?p=preview

### HTML

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <style type="text/css">
    .scroll-div {
      height: 300px;
      overflow: scroll;
      margin-top: 6.5em;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    .anchor {
      border: 2px dashed red;
      padding: 10px 10px 200px 10px;
    }
    .my-fixed-header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .my-fixed-header > a {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 5px 15px;
    }
    .html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

  </style>
 <body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
   <div class="my-fixed-header">
      <a href="index.html#/#anchor{{x}}"  ng-click="gotoDiv(x)" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5]">
        Go to Div {{x}}
      </a>
     <div style="border:1px solid;padding:20px;width:100%;background:yellow;">Header</div>
   </div>
    <div class="scroll-div">      
      <div style="border:1px solid;" id="anchor{{group.id}}"  ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:item.value ">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open(group)">{{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

### SCRIPT

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$location,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

$scope.gotoDiv = function(x) {
          $scope.groups.forEach(a=>{
               console.log(x);


            a.isOpen = true;


          });



     };

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      id:'1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      id:'1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      id:'2',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      id:'3',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]

    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      id:'4',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      id:'5',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    }
  ];
$scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
});
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: instead of scroll I need to hide other div and show particular/matching div.

Comment: That's your need, not your question ;) We are not here to do your work. Try it yourself and describe what _exactly_ are you having trouble with.

Comment: Actually I am new to angularjs,I am not getting the logic here also how to hide other div except matching div

Comment: Can't you accomplish this with tabs in bootstrap? Just a suggestion.

Comment: As per bootstrap I can only scroll to particular div,but here I need to hide other div completely and only shows particular div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the visibility for each div and then toggle it as per the link clicks... for this to work, we need to store the visibility status against each object in our `$scope.groups` array. We do this by introducing a new variable `visible` in each object of the array, we set it to true for the object we need to display by default - the rest can be displayed after clicking on the links at the top.

Check the working demo below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  $scope.visibleGrid=-1;

  $scope.gotoDiv = function(x) {
    $scope.visibleGrid=x;
    $scope.groups.forEach(a => {
      /* console.log(" we got ID:" + x + " & looking it against the ID:" + a.id); */
      a.isOpen = true;
    });

  };

  $scope.groups = [{
      title: 'title 0',
      id: '0',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      id: '1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      id: '2',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      id: '3',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]

    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      id: '4',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      id: '5',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    }
  ];
  $scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
});
```

```css
.scroll-div {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-top: 6.5em;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.anchor {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  padding: 10px 10px 200px 10px;
}

.my-fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.my-fixed-header>a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 15px;
}

.html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>

<body ng-app="app" >

  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div class="my-fixed-header">
      <a href="#{{x}}" ng-click="gotoDiv(x)" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5]">
        Go to Div {{x}}
      </a>
      <div style="border:1px solid;padding:20px;width:100%;background:yellow;">Header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-div">
      <div style="border:1px solid;" id="anchor{{group.id}}" ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:item.value ">
        <ng-container ng-if='visibleGrid == group.id || visibleGrid == -1'>
          <div class="parents" ng-click="open(group)">{{ group.title }}
          </div>
          {{ group.content }}
          <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
            <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
              <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**UPDATE**: (after user comment) by default, all data to be displayed and then after a particular click, only relevant section will stay visible

**UPDATE #2**: (after user's 2nd comment) same result without adding anything to the JSON's data

Comment: Thanks.. Is it possible to load all the data on load.. Now it is showing only first data

Comment: check now... is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: by default, the visible flag is set to true... Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it works for you

Comment: Is it possible without modifying anything in JSON... Since in JSON there won't be visible column

Comment: @carreankush, sure we can, check the attached answer updated